# What other things can I use my dumb terminal for?

Tags: command-line, serial-port, virtual-terminal

I have a serial dumb terminal.  I use a null modem via a serial port to connect it to my Ubuntu computer.  It comes in handy when X freezes and the there is no response using the keyboard.  If I can boot from my dumb terminal I can fix my system.  What other things can I use my dumb terminal for?

Here is a link you can read about a dumb terminal.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a performance monitoring program and keep an eye on the consumption of CPU and other resources as you initiate programs and functions with Ubuntu's graphic user interface.

You could also write a program to ring the bell on the terminal to announce the time.

Anything you could do with gnome-terminal should be possible with your terminal. If you happen to have problems with extra garbage on the screen and misplaced information as you proceed you may have to change the terminal type terminfo and termcap use for your device. `apropos terminfo` would be a good place to start.